# Будет ли Singleton работать со всеми пользователям или только с одним?

Tags: php, база-данных, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования, singleton

Если реализовать класс работы с базой данных по шаблону Singleton, то как будет происходить процесс его функционирования?

Проект реализовать по шаблону MVC. Скажем, что есть 100 пользователей, которые работают с разными моделями одной базой данных. На данный момент при обращении к модели создается экземпляр класса базы данных и выполняется работа. То есть 100 человек эквивалентно 100 соединений.

Что будет, если класс работы с базой данных организовать как Singleton? Будет ли всего 1 соединение для всех пользователей (параллельно)? Если нет, то почему и какие средства можно предпринять для установления всего 1 соединения для параллельной работы многим пользователям.

Comment: Синглтон гарантирует, что во время исполнения скрипта вы не сможете создать еще один экземпляр того же класса. Как только скрипт завершен - инстанс синглтона умирает вместе со скриптом. Поэтому для каждого пользователя создается свой синглтон во время исполнения его скрипта.

Comment: @u_mulder Это скорее, полноценный ответ, а не комментарий.